# Trigger error- System.StringException: Starting position out of bounds:

Tags: trigger, opportunity, error

There are some lead gen profiles in our salesforce which I want them to create opportunity for any appointment created and Stage to be selected as "MQL" which is newly introduced in our sales process cycle.

Getting error while adding new record by Lead Gen profile users.
`Oppourtunity_CheckStage: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Starting position out of bounds: 6 Trigger.Oppourtunity_CheckStage: line 18, column 1`

There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was `Apex trigger Oppourtunity_CheckStage caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Oppourtunity_CheckStage: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Starting position out of bounds: 6: Trigger.Oppourtunity_CheckStage: line 18, column 1`

Trigger - Code

```
trigger Oppourtunity_CheckStage on Opportunity (before update) 
{


  Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator' Limit 1];
  
  System.debug('***** User Profile ID: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId() + ' Admin ProfileId: ' + p.Id);
  if (UserInfo.getProfileId() != p.Id)
  {
    for (opportunity o: trigger.new)
    {
      
      Opportunity originalOppty = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.id);
      String CurrentStage = o.StageName;
      String PriorStage = originalOppty.StageName;
      
      string PriorStageStringNumber;
      string CurrentStageStringNumber = CurrentStage.substring(6, 7);
      
      System.Debug('****** Prior StageName' + originalOppty.StageName);
      if (originalOppty.StageName != null)      
      {
        PriorStageStringNumber = PriorStage.substring(6, 7);        
      }
      else
      {
        PriorStageStringNumber = '8';
      }
      integer Prior;
      if (PriorStage == 'Closed Won'  || PriorStage == 'Closed Lost')
        Prior = 0;
      else
        Prior = integer.valueOf(PriorStageStringNumber);
      
      
      integer Current; 
      if (o.StageName == 'Closed Lost' || o.StageName == 'Closed Won')
      {
        Current = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        Current = integer.valueOf(CurrentStageStringNumber);
      }
            
      
      if (PriorStage != CurrentStage)
      {
        //  this section is for checking backward stages
        if (PriorStage == 'Closed Won'  || PriorStage == 'Closed Lost')
        {
          o.addError('You cannot go backwards in stages.');
          break;
        }  
        system.debug('***** Prior Stage: ' + PriorStage);
        system.debug('***** Current Stage: ' + CurrentStage);
        
        if (CurrentStage != 'Closed Won'  && CurrentStage != 'Closed Lost')
        {

          
          if (Prior < Current)
          {
            o.addError('You cannot go backwards in stages.');
          }
        } 
        
        //  This section is for checking forward stages
        if (CurrentStage == 'Closed Lost')
        {
          //  Criteria for going to this stage are ! Order book stages.
          if (Opportunity_Utils.Find_Stage_Type(PriorStage) == Opportunity_Utils.Order_Book)
            o.addError('Opportunities in Order Book stages cannot be moved to Closed Lost.');          
        }
        
      }
      /*if (PriorStage == CurrentStage)
      {
        system.debug('***** Prior: ' + Prior  + ' Current: ' + Current + '   Remarks: (' + o.Remarks__c + '   Results (' +  o.Result__c + ')');
        //  Here we are checking to make sure that they have filled in calculator fields.
        if (Current < 5)
        {
          
          if (o.Logic_for_Revenue_Calculation__c  == '' || o.Result__c == null)
            o.addError('You must supply revenue calculation info in this stage.');
        }
      }*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check that the contents of the variable StageName has length 8 if you want to take the substring from 6-7. Otherwise you cannot guarantee you'll reach out of bounds.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn you should post this as an answer

Comment: @Manasvi Please do not edit an answer to ask clarification. Instead, click on the link "Add a comment" just below the answer to post your question or request more details

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the contents of the variable StageName has length 8 if you want to take the substring from 6-7. Otherwise you cannot guarantee you'll reach out of bounds and get this exception.

```
trigger Oppourtunity_CheckStage on Opportunity (before update) 
{


  Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator' Limit 1];
  
  System.debug('***** User Profile ID: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId() + ' Admin ProfileId: ' + p.Id);
  if (UserInfo.getProfileId() != p.Id)
  {
    for (opportunity o: trigger.new)
    {
      
      Opportunity originalOppty = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.id);
      String CurrentStage = o.StageName;
      String PriorStage = originalOppty.StageName;
      
      string PriorStageStringNumber;
      string CurrentStageStringNumber = CurrentStage.substring(6, 7);
      
      System.Debug('****** Prior StageName' + originalOppty.StageName);
      if (PriorStage != null && PriorStage.length()>=8) // adapt this condition according to the syntax of PriorStage     
      {
        PriorStageStringNumber = PriorStage.substring(6, 7);        
      }
      else
      {
        PriorStageStringNumber = '8';
      }
      integer Prior;
      if (PriorStage == 'Closed Won'  || PriorStage == 'Closed Lost')
        Prior = 0;
      else
        Prior = integer.valueOf(PriorStageStringNumber);
```